# DNS setup for no subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I can't figure out why going to my website, `mywebsite.app` does not work, while `www.mywebsite.app` and `anythinghere.mywebsite.app` works.

Am I missing something in this DNS list?

All these CNAMEs area working

1. `*` eg `whocares.mywebsite.app` points to my main S3 bucket and works
2. `admin` eg `admin.mywebsite.app` points to my secondary S3 bucket and works
3. `api` eg `api.mywebsite.app` points to my heroku app and works
4. `www` eg `www.mywebsite.app` points to my main S3 bucket and works
5. Those long complicated ones are for AWS certificate management

What am I missing to get `mywebsite.app` ie without any subdomain doing the same thing as the `*` rule? Why does the `*` not include "nothing"?
[image]

Comment: You didn't define any records for it, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: But I can't add a blank subdomain. There must be a value for "name", so.. what would it be?

Comment: It is `@`, as shown in all the other entries and in the documentation.

Comment: Ok well it's not allowed for CNAME so

Comment: Of course not; you can't set a CNAME for the naked domain.

Comment: Sorry, I took a minute to go through your post again in case I missed something. It looks like you want to host it on an S3 bucket. This requires your domain's DNS records be hosted on Route 53 so you can use Amazon's fake ALIAS record to point to the S3 bucket. You also have to set up CloudFront if you want it to work on HTTPS. Amazon has a [complete walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) in their docs.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` CNAME record provides an alias for arbitrary *sub*domains (third level), but for the second-level domain itself, there's no entry. Depending on the tool/user interface you're using, a dummy `@` name may be required.

Comment: But I can't add a blank subdomain. There must be a value for "name", so.. what would it be?